# Regex: How to split by "=" and not by "!="

Tags: python, regex

```
>> s1 = "a=b"
>> s2 = "a!=b"

>> re.compile("SOMTHING").split(s1)
>> # I expect ['a','1']

>> re.compile("SOMTHING").split(s2)
>> # I expect ['a!=1'] and NOT ['a!,'1']
```

I tried `compile([^!]=).split(s2)` but that doesn't work and give `['','1']`

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this.

```
>>> s1 = "a=b"
>>> s2 = "a!=b"
>>> r = re.compile(r"(?<!!)=")
>>> r.split(s1)
['a', 'b']
>>> r.split(s2)
['a!=b']
```

Depending on your inputs, you might also need to look ahead:

```
>>> s3 = "a==b"  # I guess you wouldn't want to split that
>>> r.split(s3)
['a', '', 'b']
>>> r = re.compile(r"(?<![!=])=(?!=)")
>>> r.split(s3)
['a==b']
```